# My call to contract method not throw error but stuck, why?

Tags: solidity, web3js, evm, revert-opcode

when I call a contract method, which should revert and throw error:

Contract souce code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract VeryGoodNftWithMaxSupply is ERC721URIStorage {

  uint256 private _currentId = 0;
  address public rootAddress = address(0);
  uint256 public _maxSupply = 3;

  event Minted(address to, uint256 nftId, address minter);

  modifier shouldLessThanMaxSupply(){
    require(
      _currentId < _maxSupply, "Reached max supply, no available nft left"
    );
    // 下划线表示被hook方法的内容。 会在编译、执行的时候做个替换
    _;
  }

  constructor() ERC721("VeryGoodNftWithMaxSupply", "VGNWM") {
    rootAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  function mint(address to) external shouldLessThanMaxSupply{
    uint256 nftId = _currentId + 1;
    _mint(to, nftId);
    _currentId = nftId;
    address from = msg.sender;
    emit Minted(to, nftId, from);
  }
}
```

and the script calling this contract (callVeryGoodNftWithMaxSupply.js ） looks like:

```
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x7eB6D07B6A69a2Be809dAed88d456C1460aA7C3e"
const contractJson = require('./build/contracts/VeryGoodNftWithMaxSupply.json')

module.exports = async function (callback) {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract( contractJson.abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS );

  const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()

  // This method will meet the error ( rever : max nft supply reached ... ) 
  const tx = contract.methods.mint('0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A')

  const receipt = await tx
  .send({
    from: (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0], 
    gas: await tx.estimateGas(),
  })
  .once('sending', (payload) => {
    console.info("-- in sending..., payload: ", payload)
  })
  .once('sent', (payload) => {
    console.info("-- in sent..., payload: ", payload)
  })
  .once("transactionHash" , (txHash) => {
    console.log(`Mining transaction ... network: ${network}, tx: ${txhash}`)
    // console.log(`https://${network}.etherscan.io/tx/${txhash}`)
  })
  .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.info("-- in receipt...", receipt)
    console.log('====== total: ')
    console.log(receipt)
    console.log('====== events.Minted: ', receipt.events.Minted)
    // Success, you've minted the NFT. The transaction is now on chain!
    console.log(
        `Success: The NFT has been minted and mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`)
    callback()
  })
  .on('confirmation', (confNumber, receipt, lastBlockHash) => {
    console.info("-- in confirm...", receipt)
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(`An error happened: ${error}`)
    callback()
  })

}
```

However, when I typed the command and press enter, it just stuck , no error , and the program is always running,

and when I press `ctrl + c` , error message is shown:

```
 ^CUnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Reached max supply, no available nft left
  {
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Reached max supply, no available nft left\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\utils\\runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at module.exports (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\utils\\gas\\guestimation.js:142:32)",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
....
```

What could I do to make it throw error ,but not stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:  if the contract call has potential problem, it will throw error when we estimate the gas.

```
  const receipt = await tx
  .send({
    from: (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0], 
    gas: await tx.estimateGas(),   // <---  in this step, the error occurs
  })
```

I found this clue when call the contract using remix + metamask, I found this:

[image]

so the solution is quite simple: just catch this error when you `estimateGas`, the improved code looks like:

```
  console.info("== before estimateGas: ")
  let gas = await tx.estimateGas()
  .then(function(e){
    console.log(e)
  }).catch(function(e){
    throw("got error, lets stop:", e)
    console.log(e)
  })
  console.info("== after estimateGas: ", gas)
```